# How to not make scaling snap to 3D Cursor?

Tags: scale, 3d-cursor

Whenever I try to rescale the points in my cup, they always scale in the direction of the 3D cursor. How can I make it so that they are scaled independent of the position of the 3D cursor? 
[image: Picture of problem]

Sorry if this is a really easy thing to configure - I have spent almost an hour looking through stack exchange and the blender docs and could find nothing on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to come back to *Pivot Point* > *Median Point* instead of *3D Cursor*.

[image]

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[image: You need to click here and select individual origins to fix this issue..]

You need to click here and select individual origins to fix this issue